# .htaccess not redirecting when url contains ? or =

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can anyone tell me how to redirect if incoming URL contains certain text as having real trouble with this..

For instance:

RedirectMatch 301 /files/9453041/batch-BiDA http://secondsite.com   (THIS WORKS)

RedirectMatch 301 /?load=/files/9453041/batch-BiDA http://secondsite.com   (THIS DOESNT WORK)

Only the first of the above two redirects work, not sure why but the second containing the /?load= doesnt redirect.  Can someone either tell me what i need change on the second line for it to work?

Or perhaps I was thinking if it couldnt be made to work if it would be possible to redirect every incoming url that has "mysite.com/?load=/whatever/whatever" to "mysite.com/whatever/whatever"?

Many thanks for any help...

Comment: Escape the ? and = with a backslash: \? and \= so it looks like /\?load\=/files.....

Comment: @Deryck RedirectMatch doesn't match query strings. you need mod rewrite, not mod alias.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy true story ^

Answer (score 0):

In order to match query strings (everything after the `?`), you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable using a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^load=/files/9453041/batch-BiDA
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://secondsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

---

You can also use the `[OR]`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^load=/files/9453041/batch-BiDA [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^load=/files/35356441/batch-546A 
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://secondsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

etc.

But if you don't care what follows the `/files/` part, just match the numebrs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^load=/files/[0-9]+/batch-[0-9A-Za-z]+ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://secondsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) ive had partial success with it but need to over come a problem when using the code as suggested... The problem im having is i have a many links that need redirecting but the code causes a server unavailable error when any of the urls I add to the above code included one open bracket "(" I have many links that have characters + ( etc and open brackets too these url links are outside my control so my question is how would I cont...

Comment: deal with this link to redirect it?   ^load=/storage/6780109/seven_7_(Active+_v2.0.6_Reloaded_-_DAN_%5BTeam_

Comment: can I use any wild card or partial matching so that I can work around these problem characters?  Thanks again for your help im pulling my hair out with it! :p

Comment: Actually I think I have solved this by replacing the special characters with a full stop .  seems to be working the only thing is i have to write it like this or it does function                                                    

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^load=/files/9453041/batch-BiDA
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://secondsite.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^load=/files/35356441/batch-546A
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://secondsite.com/ [L,R=301]

I have to do the rule after every condition is there a fix for that?

Many thanks for your help...

Comment: @user2872083 if you have specific numbers after the `/files/` bit, then you have no choice but to enumerate them, but you can at least link them together with an `[OR]`. Otherwise, if you don't care what the numbers are, you can match against any number, see edit above